# UiTableViewController delegate methods not called in UITableViewController subclass

Tags: ios

Why isn't the `numberOfSectionsInTableView` method not being called? It's called if I add `[self.tableView reloadData]` in `viewDidLoad`, but even then, `cellForRow` does not get called.

**Edit**: I updated the following code to register the nib for the `UITableViewCell`.

In a `UIViewController`, I have:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];        
    XXFeedTableViewController *tableViewController = [[XXFeedTableViewController alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewStylePlain];
   tableViewController.view.frame = self.view.bounds;
   [self addChildViewController:tableViewController];
}
```

#### XXFeedTableViewController.h

```
@interface XXFeedTableViewController : UITableViewController
@end
```

#### XXFeedTableViewController.m

```
#import "XXFeedTableViewController.h"
#import "XXFeedTableViewCell.h"

@interface XXFeedTableViewController ()

@end

@implementation XXFeedTableViewController

- (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewStyle)style {
    self = [super initWithStyle:style];
    if (self) {
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    [self.tableView registerNib:[UINib nibWithNibName:@"XXFeedTableViewCell" bundle:nil] forCellReuseIdentifier:@"XXFeedTableViewCell"];
}

#pragma mark - Table view data source

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return 5;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"XXFeedTableViewCell";
    XXFeedTableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];
    cell.textLabel.text = @"Hey";
    return cell;
}

@end
```

Apple docs say:

> If no nib file is specified or if the nib file defines no data source
>   or delegate, UITableViewController sets the data source and the
>   delegate of the table view to self. When the table view is about to
>   appear the first time it’s loaded, the table-view controller reloads
>   the table view’s data.

Comment: Add `[self addChildViewController:tableViewController];`

Comment: Same problem, except now the screen is black rather than showing empty cells.

Comment: where have u set the delegates and data source

Comment: The app docs say when there's no nib, "UITableViewController sets the data source and the delegate of the table view to self."

Comment: Ok, You are using storyboard from what I can see. Are you sure you have properly connected tableViewController delegate and dataSource? Do it either in code after tableViewController initialization or in storyboard editor. p.s. Why u're adding it as as subview to another viewcontroller?

Comment: Are you just using the default table view that you get with a table view controller? No xib, no storyboard?

Comment: Correct rdelmar, no xib, no storyboard.

Comment: I think you need to register the class (UITableViewCell) with the identifier you use in cellForRowAtIndexPath.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't see that you had a custom cell class. The way Apple recommends to do that now is to register the nib file, then you don't need to load the nib in cellForRowAtIndexPath. If you do that, you're guaranteed to get a cell, so your if (cell == nil) clause will never run.

Comment: Have you written any code in `viewDidLoad`? There can be some code blocking call of `cellForRow...`

Comment: As a precaution, correct your way of getting custom cell from nib. `NSArray *nib = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"XXFeedTableViewCell" owner:nil options:nil];
   cell = (ROFeedTableViewCell *)[nib objectAtIndex:0];`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this, and see if it works. This is the way Apple recommends now with a nib based cell.

```
-(void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    [self.tableView registerNib:[UINib nibWithNibName:@"XXFeedTableViewCell" bundle:nil] forCellReuseIdentifier:@"XXFeedTableViewCell"];
}

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return 5;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"XXFeedTableViewCell";
    ROFeedTableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];
    cell.textLabel.text = @"Hey";
    return cell;
}
```

**After Edit:**

In your initial controller, you should add the table view controller as a child controller before you add its subview:

```
   XXFeedTableViewController *tableViewController = [[XXFeedTableViewController alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewStylePlain];
   self addChildViewController:tableViewController];
   tableViewController.view.frame = self.view.bounds; 
   [self.view addSubview:tableViewController.view]; 
   [tableViewController didMoveToParentViewController:self];
```

Comment: Thanks, but the screen is still black.

Comment: @RosePerrone, When you add the tableViewController's view, you should set the frame. It could be that its size is 0. You should also do the [self addChildViewController:tableViewController].

Comment: thanks, but even with these changes, the screen is black and the tableView delegate methods aren't called.

Comment: @RosePerrone, Is viewDidLoad called? If so, try logging self.tableView there to make sure it's not nil.

Comment: I print this in `viewDidLoad`: `(lldb) po self.tableView
<UITableView: 0xaa85200; frame = (0 20; 320 460); clipsToBounds = YES; autoresize = W+H; gestureRecognizers = <NSArray: 0x9b822d0>; layer = <CALayer: 0x9b7f100>; contentOffset: {0, 0}>`

Comment: @RosePerrone, I think I see the problem. Your XXFeedTableViewController is being deallocated because you don't have a strong reference to it in your initial controller. Create a property for it there.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/33607/discussion-between-rdelmar-and-rose-perrone)